# Make a div to disappear on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div disappear on `hover` with CSS but I don't want it reappearing when moving the mouse again. I know I can do it with Javascript like this:

```
function CloseRegister() {
    var regdiv = document.getElementById("register");
    register.style.display = "none";
}
```

But I want it to have CSS transitions so it loses it takes like 2 seconds to disappear (without reappearing again)..

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
.register
{
    background-color:Purple;
    transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
}
.register:hover
{
    opacity:0;
}
</style>

<div id="register" class="register" style="position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:25%; left:25%;"></div>
```

### EDIT:

Fixed it with @[GolezTrol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511529/goleztrol)'s help:

```js
function CloseRegister() {
    var regdiv = document.getElementById("register");
    register.onmouseup = function () {
        register.onmouseup = null;
        register.classList.add('hovered');
        setTimeout(function () { register.style.display = 'none'; }, 2000);
    }
}
```

```css
.register
{
    background-color:Purple;
    transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
}
.register.hovered
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div onmousedown="CloseRegister()" id="register" class="register" style="position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:25%; left:25%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript anyway, you can use the onmouseover event. When that event occurs for the first time, you can add a class that runs the CSS transformation.

```js
var regdiv = document.getElementById("register");

var hoverEvent = function(){
    // Remove the event so it doesn't get called a million times while fading.
    register.removeEventListener('mouseover', hoverEvent);
    // Add the class that takes care of the animation.
    register.classList.add('hovered');
  
    // After a while, still add 'display: none' to remove the element from flow, if needed.
    setTimeout(2000, function(){register.style.display = 'none';})
};

register.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverEvent);
```

```css
.register
{
    background-color:Purple;
    transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
}
.register.hovered
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="register" class="register" style="position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:25%; left:25%;"></div>
```

Comment: It works great, but if I use Javascript, then I use it with `onclick`. Problem with it is, it only activates `hovered` class if I take the mouse out of the div and hover it again.

Comment: It should work on any movement on the div. Only when the mouse is still on top of the div, it doesn't work. As soon as you move, the event fires.

Comment: I changed the listener to `onmouseclick` and trying to figure out how to perform another click on the div as it is required by the code..

Comment: If you change both occurrences of `mouseover` to `click`, the div hides when it is clicked. If you want it to reappear (from code), set display to `block` and remove the class `hovered`.

Comment: Had it fixed. I was calling the function with `onclick` from the div instead of `onmousedown`. It works great now!

Answer (score 1):

the best approach is to listen to the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)  and [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```js
$("#register").hover(function(){ 
  $(this).addClass("delete");
  $(this,".delete").on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
    $(this).remove()
 });
})
```

```css
.register
{
    background-color:Purple;
    transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
}
.register.delete
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register" class="register" style="position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:25%; left:25%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood with first post.  This has the same result with CSS3 animations, but won't be supported in older versions of IE.

```
.register
{
    background-color:Purple; 
}
.hovered-anim
{
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s !important;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes example {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(".register").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).addClass("hovered-anim");
});
```

You can view the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tc78axye/2/

Comment: Misunderstood.  Revised.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set

```
 .register:hover {
 opacity:0
 }
```

to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden;` if you want to keep the layout without using JavaScript

Comment: If you set the display to none, it will flicker in and out because as soon as it is hidden, it won't be hovered over anymore.